# cat file contents to temp file but file/folder doesn't exist

Tags: linux, bash

good day all

this is part of a larger function, but I get this error and can't figure out what is the problem:

script name "connected.sh"

running this

```
 cat "$logfile" | grep "$searchstring"
```

returns results perfectly, however when I insert this into the bash function, with the following code: (this is line 41, line 40 I create the tempout file & 41 is a simple echo)

```
 "$(cat "$logfile" | grep "$searchstring")" >> "$tempout"
```

this is printed in the terminal:

```
./connected.sh: line 41: Fri Nov  6 14:29:14 2015 us=68416 xyz/x.x.x.x.184:44595 MULTI: primary virtual IP for xyz/x.x.x.x:44595: 10.0.0.12 
Fri Nov  6 14:29:27 2015 us=606987 xyz/x.x.x.x:40223 MULTI: primary virtual IP for xyz/1x.x.x.x:40223: 10.0.0.10 
Fri Nov  6 15:46:58 2015 us=712031 xyz/x.x.x.x4:54911 MULTI: primary virtual IP for xyz/x.x.x.x:54911: 10.0.0.12: No such file or directory
```

what is causing this "./connected.sh: line 41: ... No such file or directory"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 "$(cat "$logfile" | grep "$searchstring")" >> "$tempout
```

Is executing the line found by grep in your $logfile (that is what the "$" at the beginning of your outer parenthesis does) and then storing the output in $tempout.  From your explanation it appears you are trying to redirect the line found by grep into $tempout. which would just be:

```
cat "$logfile" | grep "$searchstring" >> "$tempout"
```

Is that what you're trying to do?